# linked list inside a linked list (nested linked list)

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>



  struct module {

 char name[10];
  int note;
  struct module * next;

    };
  typedef struct module module;


  struct student {
  char name[10];
  char adress[20];
  struct student * next;
  module * head;

 } ;
 typedef struct student student;


 student *etudiant=NULL;



  module* add_module(char name[],int note){
module *p=(module*)malloc(sizeof(module));
p->note=note;
p->next=NULL;
strcpy(p->name,name);

return p;
 }



 void add_student(char name[], char adress[])

 {

     student *p=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
     strcpy(p->name,name);
     strcpy(p->adress,adress);

     p->head= add_module("algo",15);
     p->next=NULL;

     if (etudiant==NULL){

    etudiant=p;
}
else{
    student *q = etudiant;

while(q->next!=NULL){

    q=q->next;

     }
     q->next=p;
          }
 }


    void print_module(module *m){

 if (m==NULL)
 {
     printf("NULL");


 }
 else
 {
     while(m->next!=NULL){
         printf("%s   ",m->name);
    printf("%d\n",m->note);
    m=m->next;
     }

 }


}


 void print(){
 student *p;
 module *m;
 p = etudiant;
 if (etudiant==NULL){

printf("NULL");
 }

 else
 {
while (p->next!=NULL);
 {
     printf("%s   ",etudiant->name);
     printf("%s   ",etudiant->adress);

     m = p->head;
     while(m != NULL){
        printf("%s ",m->name);
        printf("%d ",m->note);
        m= m->next;
     }
     p = p->next;
      }
 }


 }

int main () {

    add_student("jack","nowhere");
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to create is a list inside a list exemple

```
  Student list :

  Student || subject || ==> student 2 || subject
          |                          |
          maths                      POO
          |                          |
          physiques                 English
```

that's an approximate paiting of my structure, i arrived to add one subject to one student, but i don't know how to add more.
thanks in advance.

I defined the student list as a global one since i would be needing only one list containing all students

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: what is module? is it inside of student?

Comment: traverse the student list and find the student to which you want to add the module, then just traverse its module list and add the module to its module list.

Comment: @rajev how ?
sean i don't know if i get u well, but every student have a linked list of subjects.

Comment: I haven't seen it in detail about module code, but by looking at a diagram, I don't see the point of putting module as another list. So If it is not necessary, remove module and add it to struct of student. For subjects for second list in the diagram, construct simple struct for subject and attch it in student.

Comment: im supposed to make modules(subjects) as a linked list.

Comment: Also, it is really difficult to see because of the indentation.

Comment: :P well ye modules are the subject eg: maths phyisuqe, etc, so basically it's a linked list that has char and it's mark, and every student have unique subjects, (some students may have same subjects)

but the student linked list is one for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let this is your student list :

```
Student1 ==> student2 ==> NULL
   |            |
   maths        POO
   |            |
   physiques    English
```

Now if you want to add module "Computer Science" to student2 then you have to do the following steps:

1. traverse the student list to find the student2.
2. then traverse its module list.
3. add module "Computer Science" to list(you can add anywhere as per your requirement).

Your function will be like this:

```
typedef struct student student;
void addModule(char studentName[], char subject[], int note) {
    // searching student in the list..
    if(etudiant != NULL) {
        struct student *s = etudiant; //start of the list
        while(s && strcmp(s->name, studentName) != 0)
            s = s->next;

        if(s != NULL) {
            // creating module...
            module* new = (module*)malloc(sizeof(module));
            strcpy(new->name, subject);
            new->note = note;
            new->next = NULL;

            //adding module to the front of the module list of student s ...
            module* tmp = s->head;
            s->head = new;
            new->next = tmp;
        }
    }
}

void add_student(char name[], char adress[]) {
    student *p=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
    strcpy(p->name,name);
    strcpy(p->adress,adress);
    p->next=NULL;

    if (etudiant==NULL){
        etudiant=p;
    }
    else {
        struct student *q = etudiant;

        while(q->next!=NULL){
            q=q->next;
        }
        q->next=p;
    }
    addModule(p->name, "algo", 15);
}

 int main() {
    add_student("A", "XYZ");
    addModule("A", "CS", 1);
    addModule("A", "MECH", 1);

    add_student("B", "PQR");
    addModule("B", "DAA", 1);
    addModule("b", "SE", 1);

    //printing the list...
    student *q = etudiant;
    while(q != NULL) {
        module *p = q->head;
        printf("%s -> ", q->name);
        while(p != NULL) {
            printf("%s ", p->name);
            p = p->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        q = q->next;
    }
 }
```

Comment: what if i want to add student's modules at the creating of that student

Comment: create the student and just add the modules as in the above function. You don't have to traverse student list in this case coz you already know where to add modules :p

Comment: one more question, module pointer is a local one or a global one ? do I need to pass a pointer to module or student in the main function ? :p

Comment: it should be local coz you don't need it outside the function in the above    implementation. Only one global pointer is needed which will point to the start of the student list, here it is `etudiant`.

Comment: well, i did not really quite understand ur logic, and when i tried it my program crashed, it'd be good if u add some exemple names, thanks

Comment: you have to pass the name of student to which you want to add the module, module name(subject), and note. The function will add the module  to the student with name you will pass in first argument, to the front of its module list.

Comment: can you write some code ? i'll use it as a start. (thanks)

my logic ended up like a mess

Comment: i was a ble to add one student with multiple modules, but if added another student, then add some module to this one it won't work 

add_student("mouttie","biskra");
addModule("mouttie","nowhere", 20);
         addModule("mouttie","poo", 20);
        addModule("mouttie","archi", 20);
        add_student("mark","blabla");
        addModule("mark","comp", 20);

Comment: it crashes at the begenining :/

Comment: nvm, you forgot a to assign the head pointer to null in the first time, thanks a lot